# Variable width of the column X of the environment tabularx

Tags: line-breaking, boxes, itemize, tabularx

Where the latex holds a variable width of the column X of the environment tabularx so that one could refer to it, for example:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2cm}X}
cześć & \parbox{\???????}{very long text or itemize}\\
\end{tabularx}
```

to make parbox in column X to be able to break line or put itemize.

Comment: it's `\hsize` but an `X` column is a parbox already, why do you want a `\parbox` there?

Comment: good to know :) sorry

Comment: I find this to be useful since the paragraph might contains forced line breaks using \\ (thus \parbox comes into play) or even the cell itself is another tabularx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The width is `\hsize` so you could use

```
\parbox{\hsize}{very long text or itemize}
```

but an `X` column is a `p` column so effectively already a parbox so in almost all cases you just need

```
very long text or itemize
```

without the `\parbox`.